# AX211 wifi is not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, kernel, iwlwifi

I have tried several answers in here, but my ax211 is still not working...

What I've got

- CPU: 13th Gen. Intel Core i7 13700H
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX4050
- RAM: 16GB LPDDR5
- Wireless lan: AX211
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04S with 5.15.0-92 kernel
- (Samsung Galaxy Book3 Ultra)

What I've tried:

1. Disabled fastboot, secure boot in BIOS
2. `sudo dpkg -i backport-iwlwifi-dkms_9858-0ubuntu3.4_all.deb`
3. `sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms`
4. update kernel to 6.2 using Ubuntu mainline program
   -> can use wifi but the graphic is not working well (no problem in recovery mode)